# cannot resolve symbol simple_list_item_1

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to use resource file `simple_list_item_1` in my `ArrayAdapter`, but its showing an error

> Cannot resolve symbol simple_list_item_1

Then i search and found out i need to use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` but its showing an error again

> Cannot resolve constructor 'ArrayAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity, int,java.lang.String)'

this is my code

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String lessonResponse) {
    Log.d("my_test", lessonResponse);

    try {
        JSONObject lessonObject = new JSONObject(lessonResponse);

        JSONArray lessonArray = lessonObject.getJSONArray("data");

        for (int i = 0; i < lessonArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject dataLessons = lessonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String jsonTitle = dataLessons.getString("lesson_title");

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTitle = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, jsonTitle);
            lessonList.setAdapter(adapterTitle);
            Log.d("Lesson Title", " " + jsonTitle);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

import

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
```

screenshot link

http://prntscr.com/8j444e

http://prntscr.com/8j44dv

Please help... thank you..

Comment: To build on Marko's answer, you should use your `for` loop to populate a `String[]` or `ArrayList<String>` and once the loop is finished, use this completed array as the argument for your `ArrayAdapter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your third argument, when creating the adapter.

The third argument should be an `ArrayList` or `Array[]` of the items to be displayed, not a `String` as in your case (**jsonTitle**).

And do not set the adapter in a for loop. Fill your ArrayList or Array and after that, set the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

It cannot resolve constructor because you probably want to use this one:

```
ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<T> objects)
```

so you're in need of an array of objects instead of a simple string. Try this:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();     
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) lessonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
if (jsonArray != null) { 
    int len = jsonArray.length();
    for (int i=0;i<len;i++){ 
      list.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
    } 
} 


ArrayAdapter<String> adapterTitle = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
lessonList.setAdapter(adapterTitle);
```